# Dismissing md-tooltip after given timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular material and I've configured md-chips this way:

```
        <md-chips md-chips-disable-input ng-model="session.participants">
          <!-- Chip removal button template -->
          <button md-chip-remove class="md-primary chip-custom" layout="row">
            <!-- Tooltip definition -->
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top" layout-align="center">
              Kick out
            </md-tooltip>
            <!-- Neat icon -->
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="md-close"  layout-align="center"></md-icon>
          </button>
        </md-chips>
```

Whilst md-chips-disable-input is a special directive that prevents the user from typing in more chips.

Everything looks great but when I press the chip remove button, the tooltip won't go away.

Is there a way that I can make the tooltip go away after a given amount of time, or another way to solve this tooltip problem?

Answer (score -1):

Use md-delay:

```
 <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-delay="1000">
   Refresh
 </md-tooltip>
```

Comment: Doesn't work... It only delays the tooltip apperance but I need it to go away